# Structures, includes, forward declarations ... C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

And again I'm stuck because of structures referencing themselves ...
I'm aware that there are thousands of questions concerning that problem, I have even posted one myself already ! 
I just can't figure it out ! I hope this time I will understand ...

I have 3 structures

```
    //file.h
    #ifndef _FILE
    #define _FILE

    #include "virtuald.h"

    typedef struct directory directory;

    struct file {
        directory* d;
    };
    file* createFile(virtuald*, directory*);

    #endif

    //directory.h
    #ifndef _DIR
    #define _DIR

    #include "file.h"

    struct directory {
        struct directory* father;
        file** listf;
        struct directory** listd;
    };
    directory* createDir(int, char*, int, directory*);

    #endif

    //virtualD.h
    #ifndef _VIR
    #define _VIR

    #include "directory.h"
    typedef struct file file;
    typedef virtuald {
        file** listf;
        directory** listd;
    }virtuald;
    int writeDir(int, directory*);

    #endif
```

How do I manage the includes and the forward declarations ? I have already tested a lot of things but I'm completely lost right now. I thought this would be working!

I got a lot of errors like:
- in directory.h : unknown type name 'file' and 'directory'
- in virtuald.h : unknown type name 'directory'

Btw I'm compiling with -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic

thank you

Comment: In what way(s) is it "not working"?

Comment: No include guards?

Comment: You seem to have a circular dependence between the 3 headers - is that really necessary?

Comment: How do you include all of this stuff in the source file?

Comment: @Scott Hunter I've edited the post, now you can see the errors

Comment: Circular inclusion without include guards is a recipe for a lot of fun.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In my main I'm using a file* and virtuald* so I'm including "file.h" and "virutald.h" in my main .c, of course I have include gards, I will edit the post

Comment: @4386427 are you sure ? I've put that include because in file.h I have a method which uses a virtuald* as a parameter

Comment: This problem isn't the slightly related to forward declarations, but with very poor program design. According to your design: "every file has a directory, and every directory has files". This is nonsense if you stop and ponder it for a while. In the real world, directories have files - files do not have directories. This is why you should sit down with pen and paper to figure out all such dependencies before you write a single line of C code.

Comment: unrelated, but IMO creating a `struct` with a single member (ie, `struct file`) is at best useless and will likely just add to your confusion. It's essentially just another `typedef`

Comment: Just don't confuse yourself with useless `typedef`s.

Comment: @MonsieurOurer: C does not support _methods_.

Answer (score 2):

#### Rule #1: Be consistent!

you seem to alternate declarations between `typedef struct A A;` and `struct A` (and then not using `struct` with  `A` afterwords).

I suggest as it was suggested yo you on your previous question to **drop the typedefs!!** They seem to only confuse you.

So let's take a very simple example.

Do this:

#### struct declaration (and definition): simple, no typedef:

```
struct A {
   int x; // whatever
   int y; // whatever
   // ... etc
};
```

#### usage of struct type: keyword `struct` followed by struct name:

```
struct A a;
a.x = 24;
a.y = 42;
```

#### (Forward) declaration:

```
struct A;
```

That's it. All you need to know. **Forget about the `typedef`s**, and **always use the keyword `struct`** before the structure name.

---

How do you apply this yo your example? Let's take your first `file`

Use use the types `directory` and `virtuald` only as pointers, so all you need is a forward declaration of them:

```
struct directory;
struct virtuald;
```

define your struct, declare your functions. Always use keyword `struct` when naming a structure type:

```
struct file {
    struct directory* d;
//  ^~~~~~
//  struct keyword
};

struct file* createFile(struct virtuald*, struct directory*);
//^~~~                  ^~~~~             ^~~~~~
// struct keyword for each naming of a struct type
```

Putting it all together:

```
// file file.h
struct directory;
struct virtuald;

struct file {
    directory* d;
};
struct file* createFile(struct virtuald*, struct directory*);
```

Comment: have I made a mistake?

Comment: I half agree with you, I think that header should themselves declare struct before define them. For example, http://pastebin.com/7bxij6e2. But whatever the OP has clearly a design problem.

Comment: @Stargateur I never saw this style of declaring your struct before the includes in your header. But I don't have that much experience in `C`.

Comment: @Stargateur at first glance it looks a simple solution. But when I think about it I think it is a problematic approach. This way the use of a header is conditioned by the existing of declarations at the include site. I.e. a header is not "self-contained". It's like in C++ when you are using `std::string` in a header without `#include <string>`. A header should be include-able as it is.

Comment: That why I prefer my solution the header is include-able everywhere without problem. The declaration are in the header. Your solution declare `directory` and `virtuald` outside their header. But both work it's just a question of style.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only pointer it is sufficient to tell the compiler that there is such struct. For example:

```
//file.h
struct directory;
struct virtuald;
struct file {
    struct directory* d;
};
struct file* createFile(struct virtuald*, struct directory*);

//directory.h
struct file;
struct directory {
    struct directory* father;
    struct file** listf;
    struct directory** listd;
};

//virtualD.h
struct file;
struct directory;
struct virtuald {
    struct file** listf;
    struct directory** listd;
};
int writeDir(int, struct directory*);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following practice.

Have 2 include files, one "public" and one "private".

The public one (whatever.h) defines the public API,
the private one (perhaps whateverP.h) defines what whatever.c
needs for implementation.

So, for example:

--------- whatever.h ------

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_WHATEVER_H
#define INCLUDED_WHATEVER_H

typedef struct VirtualDir VirtualDir;
typedef struct Directory  Directory;
typedef struct File       File;
extern File * createFile ( VirtualDir * v, Directory * d );

#endif
```

------ whateverP.h ------

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_WHATEVER_P_H
#define INCLUDED_WHATEVER_P_H
#include "whatever.h"

struct VirtualDir {
     /* whatever fields it has */
};

struct Directory {
     /* whatever fields it has */
};

struct File {
     /* whatever fields it has */
};

#endif
```

----- whatever.c -----

```
#include "whateverP.h"

extern File * createFile (
        VirtualDir * v,
        Directory *  d
) {
     /* whatever code goes here */
}
```

----- somethingthatwantstousewhatever.c -----

```
#include "whatever.h"

File * f = createFile ( blah, bleah );
```

If File, VirtualDir and Directory are implemented in different source files, the rule still holds:  blah.h holds the public API, blahP.h holds the private implementation details.